# Crop a portion of an image?

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to do what I thought would be the simplest thing, which is to crop a portion of a screenshot of a webpage and zoom in on it (yes, I'm new to Blender).

After I've imported the image and added "Effect Strip" > "Transform" I can crop "Top" and "Right" (if I check "Image Offset" that is, otherwise it STRETCHES the image), but changing values in "Bottom" and "Left" just MOVES the image, it doesn't crop it.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

instead of using the "video editor", you can use the "compositor". Add the image sequence, still image or video, then add a node "transform" and there, you set the X and Y values and scale. You can keyframe those values, so they can be animated, so the part of the image will gradually be cropped and zoomed (as you change the scale values) to fill the area you want.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that later on :-) Do you (or someone else) know why it only crops two sides?

Comment: the origin coordinates of an image start always in the same corner. When you limit (crop), you limit a distance (in pixels) to that origin.

Comment: consider also this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6712/how-to-shrink-an-image-with-the-video-sequence-editor?rq=1

Comment: What I really would like to do is basically this "crop and zoom" effect: https://youtu.be/Hel1ifQOSo0?t=690

Comment: the crop is achieved by the animation of two masks (black horizontal panels, one coming from top, and other from bot). The zoom is just a little increase on the scale. About animated masks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDGB3SNXJrM&t=359s